# SQL query for select rows from different regions of range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `entities` with entity, that has unique index `entity_id`

for example, 1 < entity_id < 1000, but count(entity_id) < 500

I want to make a sql query which select:

- 3 or less random entity if entity_id < 200,
- 3 or less random entity if 200 <=  entity_id < 400,
- 3 or less random entity if 400 <=  entity_id < 600,
- 3 or less random entity if 600 <=  entity_id < 800
- 3 or less random entity if 800 <=  entity_id

so, i want a single query and get entity from each region of entity range. It's OK if one ore more region will be empty

I have no idea how to implement it.

Please assist

Comment: You might consider using `UNION` for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ? StackOverflow is not a "make code for me please" site.

Comment: Max, yes i have. More questions off the point?

Answer (score 0):

You may write a function that returns a table and within that function first define a table with the columns that you want, something like :

```
DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE (entity_id INT, column2 INT, etc.)
```

Then, declare another table that is the same as entities but with a random number column.

```
DECLARE @EntitiesCopy TABLE (entity_id INT, rand INT);
```

Populate the @EntitiesCopy table like:

```
INSERT INTO @EntitiesCopy SELECT *, RAND() FROM entities
```

Then, write insert statements like:

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnTable(column1, column2) 
     SELECT TOP 3 * FROM @EntitiesCopy 
       WHERE (entity_id > 1) AND (entity_id < 200) 
       ORDER BY rand
```

Similarly, for the other conditions.

Then,

```
RETURN @ReturnTable
```

Comment: It seems that solution with UNION has better perfomance. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just use UNION

```
select * from entities where entity_id between 2 and 199 order by rand() limit 3
UNION
select * from entities where entity_id between 200 and 399 order by rand() limit 3
UNION
select * from entities where entity_id between 400 and 599 order by rand() limit 3
UNION
select * from entities where entity_id between 500 and 799 order by rand() limit 3
UNION
select * from entities where entity_id between 700 and 999 order by rand() limit 3;
```

Assuming, when you said 1 < entity_id < 1000 that entity_id runs between 2 and 999.

Comment: Hm, I believe that better solution is existed